# How to convert pandas series to integer for use in datetime.fromisocalendar

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I am trying to transform a pandas series which has dates in it. I'd like to take the date that is in there and return the following Monday.

Here is what I have tried:

```
db['date'] = datetime.date.fromisocalendar(db['date'].dt.year.astype(np.int64),(db['date'].dt.week+1).astype(np.int64),1)
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please share a [mre]. E.g., use `db['date'].head().to_dict()` and post the result between triple backticks (```).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty good:

```
db['date'] = db['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(7-db['date'].dt.dayofweek,'d')
```

Comment: I was writing an answer when you posted, first approach is similar to yours ;)

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

Using manual computation of a [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2024-01-01', '2024-01-10')})
df['next_Monday'] = df['date'].add(pd.to_timedelta(7-df['date'].dt.dayofweek, unit='D'))
```

Or with an [`Week`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.Week.html) offset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2024-01-01', '2024-01-10')})
df['next_Monday'] = df['date'].add(pd.offsets.Week(n=1, weekday=0))
```

Output:

```
        date next_Monday
0 2024-01-01  2024-01-08
1 2024-01-02  2024-01-08
2 2024-01-03  2024-01-08
3 2024-01-04  2024-01-08
4 2024-01-05  2024-01-08
5 2024-01-06  2024-01-08
6 2024-01-07  2024-01-08
7 2024-01-08  2024-01-15
8 2024-01-09  2024-01-15
9 2024-01-10  2024-01-15
```

If you only want to consider a next day when the day is over (i.e. if we are a Monday, keep the current date):

```
df['next_Monday'] = df['date'].add(pd.offsets.Week(n=0, weekday=0))

        date next_Monday
0 2024-01-01  2024-01-01
1 2024-01-02  2024-01-08
2 2024-01-03  2024-01-08
3 2024-01-04  2024-01-08
4 2024-01-05  2024-01-08
5 2024-01-06  2024-01-08
6 2024-01-07  2024-01-08
7 2024-01-08  2024-01-08
8 2024-01-09  2024-01-15
9 2024-01-10  2024-01-15
```